# How to get circulating supply / 'electorate' from API

Tags: polkadot-js, governance

I would like to calculate the threshold for referendums to pass. I found this article about how the calculation works, but it requires the number of coins in circulation. Is there an API endpoint for this?

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-governance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Vote Threshold](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ca1f81cd0864ae0614aaff07fa121d2d42110586/frame/democracy/src/vote_threshold.rs#L92-L105)

Let's take a look at the calculation/formula first.

There are 3 kinds of `VoteThreshold`, so the first thing you need to figure out is the voting type.

---

> [Bake Referendum](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ca1f81cd0864ae0614aaff07fa121d2d42110586/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L1716)

Then, the previous function was called here.

Through the code, we know that we need two storage items to finish the calculation.

1. [ReferendumInfoOf](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ca1f81cd0864ae0614aaff07fa121d2d42110586/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L423) contains voting type and tally/supply
2. [TotalIssuance](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ca1f81cd0864ae0614aaff07fa121d2d42110586/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L495) is the electorate

You just need to query `balances::total_issuance` and `democracy::referendum_info_of(x)`.
And fill them in the formula.

---

Tips: for the `compare_rationals`.
It's well documented in the source code.

It's just `n1 / d1 < n2 / d2` but with some overflowing protection.

If you are off-chain, using `f64`/`double` is enough. IIUC.

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm